# Is it possible to integrate Wordpress *posts* and social media (Facebook, Google+, Twitter)?

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, facebook, google-plus

Is there a plugin available that will automatically post an excerpt of a blog post (perhaps up to the more tag) to specified social media groups/pages.  So, for example, on posting an excerpt would be posted with a 'Read more' link to a user-defined Facebook group, G+ page and, possibly, twitter feed?

If not, is there a method for automating this process? Or is copy>paste the only realistic option?

(I know that Dsiqus provides the ability to link comments and social media but this functionality doesn't extend to posts, as I understand it.)

Comment: G+ does not even allow remote publishing. I guess the closest you will get is Buffer and similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for plugins: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-twitter-connect/ and http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect/ and http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-google-connect/

All require applications be built at each service for different levels of interaction with a Wordpress site, including automatic excerpt posting (except for G+), tweeting and linking.

Comment: The Google one doesn't autopost at this time. I don't believe that functionality exists yet for G+. The other 2 are fantastic however!

Comment: +1 for G+ as they don't have a POST api yet, so you can't post content via code.

Comment: Cheers very much for that - Facebook was really the central one I was after, so this should more than fit the bill.

Comment: I hadn't counted on the need for FB account verification before being able to set up integration. I'm uncertain as to whether I trust FB enough to do this, but I think the plugins above would have been/will be the ones I go for if and when this happens.

Answer (score 1):

[Social](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/social/) is great for Facebook and Twitter integration.